# how to find derbyclient.jar on mac?

Tags: java, macos, file

I'm using mac OS X 10.10.5, I want to connect to a database by importing "derbyclient.jar" to my project library. I tried going to /User/library/java, but I can't find java.

Comment: Why do you suppose it has to be on your mac? See this: http://db.apache.org/derby/derby_downloads.html

Comment: Thanks, now I got it.